# Running MSI in passive mode from WiX Bootstrapper

Tags: mysql, wix, bootstrapper, windows-installer

I'd like to include MySQL as part of my bundle. How can I run the MySQL MSI in passive mode from bootstrapper? I tried:

```
<MsiPackage Id="MySQLPackage" SourceFile="mysql-5.5.57-win32.msi"
            Vital="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" InstallCondition="InstallMySQLCheckbox">
    <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArg" Value=" /passive"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

But it doesn't work, MySQL installer runs in normal, interactive mode. There is no problem with passing /passive parameter from Windows command prompt.
Passive mode for MySQL 5.5 MSI: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html

Comment: You could define "doesn't work" a bit better and perhaps add /l*vx to your command line (with the name of a log file) to create an MSI log. I suspect the install may require elevation, and /passive may bypass the elevation request, so the install will fail for lack of privilege.

Comment: @PhilDW "doesn't work" = "doesn't make the install process unattended". The install doesn't fail and there is no problem with elevation as the bootstrapper is started in privileged mode. My problem is that the install runs as usual instead of in passive mode. It looks like /passive is ignored. The log says:
[01CC:0664][2017-08-17T00:03:21]i301: Applying execute package: MySQLPackage, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{01789E32-2A59-40BA-BCC5-350076BEEA56}v5.5.57\mysql-5.5.57-win32.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" CommandLineArg=" /passive"'

Comment: It's not exactly the same as using the /passive switch, but you can set DisplayInternalUI to "no" and this will, surprisingly, not show any of the UI for the SQL installer.

Comment: Initially I wanted to have original MSI UI, but not requiring user interaction. I thought it would be better to have it more verbose. But finally DisplayInternalUI="no" is what I'm going to use. It's more like "/quiet", not "/passive" but it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got `CommandLineArg` from, but it just passes it as a property to the MSI. There's no support in Burn for running an MSI in basic/passive UI mode.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood this. I thought CommandLineArg is some special property which allows passing msiexec arguments. Thanks.